# Updating firebase token on my server

Tags: android, mysql, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

If I'm not wrong, tokens may change over time, each time it changes the method onTokenRefresh() is executed. Now, what I want to know is, if I'm storing each token in a database on my server, how can I update it once one of them changes? should I add a primary key to my database to help me update the tokens? if so, what would the primary key be? and how would that work?

Comment: If your users have to login to your app, just use their respective `userId`s. In any case, this post is *too broad*. Consider editing out your post with more details while being more specific.

Comment: Are you asking about Device Groups?

Comment: Did you figure something out? I just asked a question related to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159375/how-should-i-update-an-existing-firebase-token-on-my-server-when-it-gets-refresh